# How do I format text array and hstore data in a CSV/TSV file for importing into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, hstore, goland, postico

I’m trying to import text arrays and hstore values into Postgres from a CSV (actually TSV) spreadsheet, but I keep getting multiples of these two errors:

`ERROR: Syntax error near '}' at position 667`

`ERROR: malformed array literal: ""   Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

My text arrays look like this: `{hello, world}`

and my hstore values look like this: `{"hello" => "world", "goodbye" => "world"}`

I'm not using the `COPY` command, I'm importing the file either through my IDE (Goland) database navigator or through Postico 2. What is the proper syntax for array and hstore data in a CSV or TSV spreadsheet for importing into Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone who needs to import array and hstore data into Postgres similar to how I am (spreadsheet exported as a TSV then imported via IDE), this is what worked for me.

For my **text arrays**, I needed to enclose them in braces and use double quotes only for the array entries that had spaces in them. No escape characters or doubling of double quotes was necessary.

**Example: {foo,"bar baz",qux}**

For my **hstore values**, no braces were needed, but double quotes for keys or values with spaces was necessary (AFAIK):

**Example: foo=>bar,baz=>"qux quuz"**

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I eliminated all spaces other than those inside quoted values (e.g. around commas and =>). Also, for array columns that can have null values, any cells in the those columns that would be null, you have to have an empty array in the cell (i.e. {}) to import without error.

I've have not yet attempted to retrieve these values with my app, but as they are now in my spreadsheet, they import without error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to double quote your string values in the text array : `{"hello", "world"}`. If this field is already double quoted in your csv/tsv file like `"{hello, world}"`, then you have to escape the double quotes inside, for instance : `"{\"hello\", \"world\"}"` if your escape character is `\` when importing the csv/tsv file in Postgres. When using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), you can specify the escape character you want, when using alternative solutions, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See my answer for what finally worked for me.